# Five year old wets through night pullup

Tags: potty-training, diaper, night-time

My son is almost five. We limit the amount of fluid he drinks several hours prior to bed. He always goes potty as part of his night time routine. He wears night time pullups during the night.

As of late, he is about 50/50 whether he pees enough to soak through the pullup.

Any new diaper recommendations or other helpful tips? Thank you!

Comment: I'll assume you go to bed significantly later than he does. Would you consider waking him last thing before you go to bed for a quick bathroom trip?  I think that if you keep the lights as low as possible and whisper, he will go right back to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem with my daughter, and what we ended up doing was a diaper change shortly before we went to bed. We did it right where she was sleeping to minimize the disturbance.

Of course, this will only work if your son is a sound sleeper and isn't woken by the diaper change, or you're quick enough that he falls asleep again immediately afterward and has no time to fully wake.

Answer (score 1):

**You could try going to a mattress liner without pull-ups**. You could pair continence with a reward system--it may help, it may not.

Five year olds make a lot of pee. There are some pull-ups that are made for older kids (Huggies has a brand), but as you noticed, even those are not enough.

If you choose to stay with pull-ups, you might consider a diaper change at some point during his sleep cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 5 yo boy who is still using pull-ups at night. We added a pad to the pull-up/diaper over a year ago when the leaks started occurring. In the US, they're often called booster pads or diaper doublers. They work very well.

We use ones that do not have any sticky portions or a plastic back. That allows the pull-up to start absorption after the pad is soaked.

We've been using Sposie, but there are multiple brands. (No connection except use)